# Create a task in SharePoint Task list using PowerAutomate Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, flow, power-automate

I want to create an item in task list of SharePoint from PA Flow. The issue i am getting is with **"Assigned To Claims"** field. I am unable to assign any user in this field. Can you please assist me in how i can create a task with assigned to claims field?

Below is the error i am getting.

```
The specified user {"Claims":"USER EMAIL"} cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it works well, please fill in the user email via Enter custom value:

[image]

If the issue still exists, we suggest you create a new task list, create a new flow to create task in this list to compare the result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was trying to add email with {"Claims":"USER EMAIL"} but it accepts only user profile property(Mail). So fetched that from O365 User action and then used **Mail** returned from that action in assigned to field.

Comment: What about adding email directly via custom value: user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com?